# Send a row to another page in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm making a vinil shop, so im trying to make the basket function, but i don't know how to send the clicked row to the other page. 
Can someone help me?
Heres the code:

```
  <div class=" vinil container-fluid col-lg-8">
   <?php

      $sql = "SELECT nomealbum, stock, price,genero, nomeinter,imgdire FROM album WHERE genero='Pop'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
             // output data of each row
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                     echo "<img style='width:130px; float:left; padding-bottom:20px; padding-right:20px;' src=uploads/" . $row["imgdire"]. "> <h1>";
                     echo "<span> " . $row["nomealbum"]. "<br> " . $row["nomeinter"]. "<br> </span>";
                     echo "<span style='float:right; padding-bottom=10px;'>" . $row["price"]. "€</span>";
                 }
                } else {
              echo "0 results";
                }

            mysqli_close($link);


   ?>
   <p><a href="buy.php" class="btn btn-danger">Comprar</a></p>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Ok i switched  over and i easely figured what's the next step, thank you for the note

Comment: You can pass parameters through as a component in the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) which makes them show up in [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: @tadman what if i want to add to a cart? I know it's with session but i don't know how to do that

Comment: All good questions, but it's also a sign that if you're not sure of the fundamentals the best plan is to learn by structured example. A great way to do this is to use a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) which will show you how to implement this. These give you patterns you can follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts.  Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: I will take a look, thank you @tadman